# How to include .js files in own Typo3 6.2 Extension?

Tags: javascript, jquery, typo3, typoscript, extbase

I made an extension in Typo3 6.2 with extension builder, extbase and fluid.
**I want to add a timepicker in the frontend.**
I found a .js file online and want to include it whenever the extension is active because I need it often.
I placed that file here: *EXT:/Resources/Public/JS/timepicker.js*.
I saw a solution in [this](http://www.schwarzer.de/blog/typo3-6-2-css-und-javascript-dateien-extbase-extensions-einbinden/) article but adding

> `page.includeJS.tx_myExtension = EXT:/Resources/Public/JS/timepicker.js`

at the bottom of my setup.txt isn't working.

I didn't define a `page` there anyway so I think this might be the reason but I really have no idea - this is my setup.txt (autogenerated) in */typo3conf/ext//Configuration/TypoScript/*:

```
plugin.tx_myext_test {
    view {
        templateRootPath = {$plugin.tx_myext_test.view.templateRootPath}
        partialRootPath = {$plugin.tx_myext_test.view.partialRootPath}
        layoutRootPath = {$plugin.tx_myext_test.view.layoutRootPath}
    }
    persistence {
        storagePid = {$plugin.tx_myext_test.persistence.storagePid}
    }
}
```

Ultimately I want my frontend function to work which already works with datepicker because I included jQuery in my root template. But I don't want to include the timepicker in there, just for my extension.

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $('.lc-datepicker').datepicker();
        $('.lc-timepicker').timepicker();
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can either use the correct syntax for `EXT:` like this:

```
page.includeJS.myextension = EXT:extkey/Resources/Public/JS/timepicker.js
```

(You forgot `extkey`.)

Keep in mind that it may improve performance of your website to use `includeJSFooter` instead of `includeJS`.

`page.includeJS` is a TypoScript property that is globally available. So if you use this in the root TS template of your site, the JavaScript file will be embedded to every page, regardless of whether the plugin is in use or not. So I suggest to use the Fluid approach below if you want to have the JS only on pages that have the plugin embedded.

To achieve this, use the Resource ViewHelper in your template:

```
<script src="{f:uri.resource(path: 'JS/timepicker.js')}"></script>
<script>
    $(function () {
        $('.lc-datepicker').datepicker();
        $('.lc-timepicker').timepicker();
    });
</script>
```

The Resource ViewHelper uses a path relative to the `Resources/Public` directory of your extension.

Comment: It's not working right now - with "page.includeJSFooter.tx_myExtension = EXT:tx_myExtension/Resources/Public/JS/timepicker.js" 
Which cache do I have to flush to be sure it's not because of it (frontend, general or system)?
And which extension name is meant exactly, where was it defined? Not the plugin name, right?

Comment: Your second example finally worked...but strange thing: I had to start at JS/... not Public otherwise the output was "Public/Public"
Wish I could figure out what problem I have with your first solution...

Comment: Sorry, my bad, the path in the`f:uri.resource` VH is relativ to `Resources/Public`. Fixed it.
I also changed `myextension` to `extkey` to emphasize that the extension key is needed which is equal to the directory of the extension within `typo3conf/ext`. Apart from the normal page cache, you should not need to delete anything else. Try reviewing the TypoScript tree in the backend to find out if your TS is applied properly.

Comment: ok, thanks for the corrections - so if `extkey` = directory of extension then what is `myextension` in `page.includeJS.myextension`?

Comment: And am I supposed to put this line in setup.txt or in my root template in the backend?
Right now if I put it in setup it doesn't work and if I put it in the root template it's always included even though I only added my extension plugin into one subpage.

Comment: I edited the question. For your needs, use the Fluid approach or jokumer's approach which I personally wouldn't prefer.

Answer (score 1):

You could define to include JS in your controller class, to ensure it only loads for your extension.

In TypoScript, to have JS file configurable:

```
plugin.tx_myext.settings.javascript.file = EXT:myext/Resources/Public/JS/timepicker.js
```

In Controller action:

```
$this->response->addAdditionalHeaderData('<script src="' .
            $GLOBALS['TSFE']->tmpl->getFileName($this->settings['javascript']['file']) .
            '" type="text/javascript"></script>');
```

Comment: but can I add the typoscript to my setup.txt file in my extension folder?
so far it's not working :(
It does load an empty header
<script src="" type="text/javascript"></script>" I wrote plugin.tx_myext.settings.javascript.file = EXT:myext/Resources/Public/JS/timepicker.js at the bottom of my setup.txt file like you said.

Comment: The drawback of this solution is that it's somehow inflexible - it's needed to change the code if the script is loaded otherwise (e.g. in global context).